# What do the components of gl_TexCoord[0] mean?

Tags: shaders, opengl-es, glsl

What are the differences between `gl_TexCoord[0].s, gl_TexCoord[0].t gl_TexCoord[0].p` and `gl_TexCoord[0].x, gl_TexCoord[0].y gl_TexCoord[0].z` ?

I understand that `gl_TexCoord[0].x, gl_TexCoord[0].y gl_TexCoord[0].z` are pixel coordinates?

But what do `gl_TexCoord[0].s, gl_TexCoord[0].t gl_TexCoord[0].p` mean and where must I use them?

Answer (score 15):

The difference is only **semantic**. Any GLSL vector can be accessed using `x/y/z/w`, `r/g/b/a` or `s/t/p/q`. Typical use is:

- `xyzw` for **space coordinates**
- `rgba` for **colours**
- `stpq` for **texture coordinates**
- if none of the above applies, any flavour can be used, but when it could be confusing, `var[0]/var[1]/var[2]/var[3]` can be used instead.

You can mix them in expressions: `foo.x = bar.q`, or even `foo.xy = bar.gb + baz.st;`. The major restriction is that swizzling can only be done using letters of the same group, *ie.* `foo.xya` is **invalid** because it mixes `xy` from `xyzw` and `a` from `rgba`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the *stpq* notation for texture coordinates (have always seen *uv* instead). I'm guessing *p* would be used for 3D textures, but in what situation would *q* be used? Edit: Nevermind I just found my answer. That would be, with TextureCubeArrays.

Comment: @DavidGouveia: No, actually. The different [texturing functions](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Sampler#Texture_lookup_functions) have different meanings. For example, accessing a `sampler2DShadow` with `texture` means that the *p* coordinate is the comparison value. Accessing a `sampler2DShadow` with `textureProj` means that the *p* coordinate is the comparison value, and the *q* coordinate is divided into the other three (*before* comparison, so *p* is actually `comparison * q`). They don't have any *intrinsic* meaning; the meaning changes depending on how they are used.

Comment: @Nicol Thanks for clearing that up. I've actually only used HLSL before and even there only ever really needed the basic tex2D and texCube intrinsics. I was unaware of the multitude of existing texturing functions. (Unrelated: Is that your real name, or just the dragon from MTG?)